# Segmentation fault core dumped in Fortran 90

Tags: segmentation-fault, fortran

I have a problem with a code that I wrote, I try to explain what my program should be do.
It reads data from a file (`.dat`), in particular values of hours, wind velocity, temperature and increments of potential temperature. Then it should elaborate these data in the subroutine `PBL_6` which call subroutines `LOG_FIT` and `LIN_FIT` that linearize a semi-log function `y = a*ln(x) + b` where `y` is wind velocity or potential temperature, and `x` is the height of measurement.

I define different arrays in the code, one for the heights (I know all the values of this array), one for the wind speed (i have 6 measurements of wind speed (`u`), each for every height), one for the temperature (`T` or `tk` in the code) and one for the increments `(dt`).  The algorithm is a simple iteration, starting from the initial condition (in `PBL_6` not in the loop `do`) it should be return me the values of `u*`,`T*` and `L`, then I make a loop with these values in the equations to find new `u*`,`T*` and `L`.

The loop will stops when it reaches the convergence for `L` (condition at the end of the loop). I think my program is correct and it compiles, but at runtime `U` receive: `Segmentation Fault Core dumped`

```
program profile
 implicit none

 character(len=12) filein,fileout
 real, dimension(6) :: u    
 real, dimension(6) :: z=(/0.5,1.,2.,4.,8.,16./)
 real, dimension(2) :: dt,tp 
 real, parameter :: k = 0.4
 real, parameter :: z0 = 0.0012
 real :: tk,ustarp, tstarp, tetai, Lp  
 integer :: ih
 integer :: row, i


 write(*,'(2x,''File input .......''/)')
 read(*,'(a12)') filein
 write(*,'(2x,''File  output........''/)')
 read(*,'(a12)') fileout

 open(unit=90,File=fileout)
 open(unit=50,File=filein) 

 write(90,130)

 do row = 1,24    
  read(50,*) ih,(u(i),i=1,6),tk,(dt(i),i=1,2)  

   tk = tk+273.15
   dt(2) = dt(2)+dt(1)  

   tp(1) = dt(1) + tk 
   tp(2) = (dt(2)-dt(1)) + tp(1) 

    call PBL_6(u,tp,z,tk,ustarp,tstarp,Lp)  

   !write(*,*) tp
   write(90,131) ih,ustarp,tstarp,Lp 
  enddo

130  format(15x,  &  
    '====================================',/,15x,   &   
    '  hour      ustar    tstar     L     ',/,15x,   &  
    '====================================')

131  format(15x,i5,4x,f7.3,2x,f7.3,2x,f7.0,2x) 

 close(50)
 close(90)

end program profile  



subroutine PBL_6(u,tp,z,T,ustarp,tstarp,Lp)             

 implicit none 

  integer :: i, j, n
  integer :: nmax 
  real :: a, b, c, d 
  real, intent(in) :: T
  real, intent(out):: ustarp,tstarp,Lp    
  real, dimension(6),intent(in) :: z
  real, dimension(6),intent(in) :: u
  real, allocatable, dimension(:)  :: uip,tetaip,L  
  real, dimension(2),intent(in) :: tp 
  real :: Lo,an,bn,cn,dn,tstar,ustar    
  real :: g=9.81 
  real :: epsilon = 0.001 
  real :: k = 0.4  

! First Guess 1/L = 0

 CALL LOG_FIT(N,z,u,a,b) 
 ustar = k*a

 CALL LOG_FIT(N,z,u,c,d) 
 tstar = k*c

 Lo = (T*ustar*ustar)/(k*g*tstar )

 allocate(uip(nmax),tetaip(nmax),L(nmax))

 do i=1,nmax
 do j=1,2  
  L(i) =  Lo

 ! Convective conditions
 uip = u - 1 + (1-16*z/L(i))**0.25 
 tetaip = tp(j) + 2*alog(0.5 + 0.5*(sqrt(1-16*z/L(i))))

 CALL LOG_FIT(N,z,uip,an,bn) 
 ustarp = k*an  

 CALL LOG_FIT(N,z,tetaip,cn,dn)
 tstarp = k*cn

  Lp = (T*ustarp*ustarp)/(k*g*tstarp)  

  if(abs(Lp-L(i)).lt.epsilon) then
    write(*,*) Lp 
   return
  endif 
 enddo
enddo

deallocate(uip,tetaip,L)   

end


subroutine LOG_FIT(N,x,y,a,b)

implicit none
 integer :: i,N
 real, dimension(N) :: x,y 
 real, dimension(:), allocatable :: xl,yl 
 real :: a,b
 real :: al,bl


  allocate(xl(N),yl(N))

  xl = alog(x)
  yl = y    


  call LIN_FIT(N,xl,yl,al,bl)
  a = al
  b = bl 

 deallocate(xl,yl)   

end  

subroutine LIN_FIT(N,x,y,a,b)

 implicit none

  integer :: N,i
  real :: Xm, Ym, xx,yy, Sxx, Sxy
  real, dimension(N) :: x, y
  real :: a,b

! Calculation of linear regression coefficients

    Xm = SUM(x)/REAL(N)
    Ym = SUM(y)/REAL(N)

     SXX = 0.
     SXY = 0.

     DO i=1,N
      xx = x(i)-Xm
      yy = y(i)-Ym
      SXX = SXX+xx**2
      SXY = SXY+xx*yy
     Enddo    

  !Coefficients 

    a = SXY/SXX
    b = Ym - a*Xm
end
```

I am no expert of Fortran therefore I would be grateful if you used simple terms.

I tried as you said Vladimir, but i have a lot of warnings now:

```
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
```

How can i solve them? i tried to initialize nmax but at runtime it gives me

```
Error: Segmentation Fault, core dumped
```

This is an example of the input files

```
 h   u1    u2    u3    u4    u5    u6    T     dt1   dt2

 0  3.02  3.41  3.83  4.27  4.87  5.75  12.7  0.16  0.20  
 1  2.73  3.05  3.42  3.85  4.43  5.29  12.5  0.16  0.19  
 2  2.16  2.45  2.77  3.21  3.88  4.91  11.9  0.17  0.03  
 3  4.04  4.48  5.00  5.54  6.14  7.05  12.9  0.12  0.15  
 4  4.02  4.50  5.03  5.58  6.12  6.88  13.0  0.19  0.20  
 5  2.76  3.12  3.51  4.00  4.62  5.53  12.1  0.24  0.27  
 6  3.93  4.35  4.88  5.48  6.18  7.13  11.7  0.24  0.26  
 7  5.30  5.95  6.66  7.36  8.04  8.98  11.9  0.25  0.29  
 8  3.98  4.44  4.98  5.50  6.10  6.95  11.1  0.19  0.18   
 9  4.07  4.44  4.97  5.53  6.09  6.84  11.4  0.14  0.13   
10  2.77  3.03  3.35  3.71  4.08  4.59  11.6  0.06  0.05   
11  3.40  3.77  4.15  4.47  4.72  4.88  14.1 -0.17 -0.20  
12  6.13  6.92  7.62  8.31  8.82  9.30  14.5 -0.29 -0.12  
13  7.21  8.06  8.89  9.69 10.37 11.04  14.6 -0.30 -0.15  
14  7.08  7.86  8.71  9.50 10.13 10.78  15.3 -0.09 -0.07  
15  8.56  9.53 10.57 11.49 12.34 13.29  14.6 -0.41 -0.10  
16  8.16  9.08 10.07 11.00 11.95 13.02  14.9 -0.15 -0.05   
17  7.96  8.88  9.89 10.88 11.76 12.81  13.6  0.12  0.14  
18  5.55  6.20  6.92  7.62  8.39  9.31  12.4  0.19  0.18  
19  4.49  5.07  5.67  6.28  6.98  7.89  11.1  0.11  0.24  
20  4.68  5.25  5.88  6.49  7.19  8.11  10.3  0.26  0.21  
21  3.43  3.86  4.34  4.84  5.47  6.41   8.9  0.28  0.20  
22  3.62  4.04  4.54  5.08  5.72  6.63   8.4  0.28  0.18  
23  4.24  4.67  5.25  5.83  6.49  7.43   7.8  0.11  0.14
```

I used your suggestion as you can see here, but i haven't the informations about errors

alessio@alessio-HP-655-Notebook-PC:~/alessio/profili$ gfortran profnew.f90 -fcheck=all -Wall -g -fbacktrace
    profnew.f90:165.1:

```
 Xm = SUM(x)/N  
 1
 Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
 profnew.f90:166.1:

 Ym = SUM(y)/N
  1
 Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
 profnew.f90:168.1:

 SXX = 0.
 1
 Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
 profnew.f90:169.1:

 SXY = 0.
 1
 Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
```

and other warnings, well now i try to initialize N and check the array x

Comment: Without the input file we cannot test it. You should first debug it yourself. Use the options the compilers have for this purpose. Try `gfortran segf.f90 -fcheck=all -Wall -g -fbacktrace`. It alread gives a couple of warnings at compile time. For example, `nmax` is not initialized.

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Prepare an example we can try. Did you actually use my previous suggestion?

Comment: Yes, now i use your suggestion, but the problem remains, what do you mean with an "example"? I tried to compile only the main program and print the values of T and it runs right, i think the problem is in the subroutine PBL or LOG_FIT

Comment: Example is a thing we can compile **and** run. We cannot run you example as we don't have any data. Give us some example of a data file. Are you sure you compiled *everything* with `-g -fbacktrace -fcheck=all `.

Comment: Also, make the subroutines internal using `contains` or move them to a module. External subroutines are evil.

Comment: I tried to put the subroutines internal with "contains" but the error remains, i attached a copy of the file used to run the code, and now i compile it in this way
     "gfortran profnew.f90 -fcheck=all -Wall -g -fbacktrace"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really used my suggestion and compile as

```
gfortran segf.f90 -fcheck=all -Wall -g -fbacktrace
```

you would get a proper [backtrace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace) when the error happens:

```
#0  0x7FB1D1D306F7
#1  0x7FB1D1D30CC4
#2  0x7FB1D12530DF
#3  0x4024E7 in log_fit_ at segf.f90:124 (discriminator 2)
#4  0x400EC3 in pbl_6_ at segf.f90:74 (discriminator 2)
#5  0x4032CB in profile at segf.f90:34 (discriminator 2)
Neoprávněný přístup do paměti (SIGSEGV)
```

Now you see the errors happens on 124 in procedure `log_fit`:

```
 xl = alog(x)
```

where `x` is an array dummy argument

`real, dimension(N) :: x,y`

It is very probable you passed the array `x` wrong.

If you paid attention to my other suggestions, I showed you `nmax` is not initialized in `PBL_6`. The other uninitialized variable is `N` and that is really bad

```
CALL LOG_FIT(N,z,u,a,b) 
ustar = k*a

CALL LOG_FIT(N,z,u,c,d) 
tstar = k*c
```

Here, `N` has no definite value and it simply must fail exactly at the point shown above.

The whole `PBL_6` is a mess for me. Think well what you want to achieve there, where should the values come from and where you want to pass them.

BTW, the warning about the nonconforming tab character means that you should not use TABs in any Fortran code. Always use spaces for indentation.

Comment: My aim in PBL_6 is to return the value of ustar, tstar and L that i called ustarp,tstarp and Lp to distinguish them from the same values in the first guess, what isn't clear in that subroutine, in your opinion?

Comment: What is of meaning of `n`, `maxn` and where should they get some value is not clear at all.

Comment: And be advised most people here are *not* boundary layer meteorologists and do not know what is the friction velocity or the Obukhov length. I know that, but that does not help me too much in comprehending your code.

Comment: I understand the situation, this code is very specific, i tried to explain the algorithm in my first post, but i thought is not possible to explain every element of the equations. Anyway nmax would be the maximum number of iterations to reach the convergence. I pass it to the subroutine, replacing N with nmax. I saw you are a professor of atmospheric and meteorological science, can I contact you in private to explain the algorithm and maybe find a solution?

Comment: I prefer not going to private channels, because this site is meant to help also others. Notice that you pass an undefined N to `log_fit` where it is used to define the size of `x` and `y`. But, in `PBL_6` the `z` and `u` have a constant size `6`. You should think if N should be 6 there, or not.